# Doctrine2 dead lock - how to handle

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, deadlock

On a symfony2 project I'm working on sometimes dead locks occur when calling `flush` on my entitymanager. This results in an exception. Most of the times this error occures just once and a second attempt to insert the same data is working correctly.

Is there a good approach to execute (flush) the same transaction again. As simple

```
$em->flush();
```

won't do, since the entitymanager gets closed if an error occures.

I've found https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/806 bit that doesn't provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine throws a RetryableException for this kind of error where you simply have to try it one more time to make it work.

The problem is that with Doctrine 2, those exceptions make the EntityManager unusable and you have to re-instantiate a new one.

Hopefully this will be corrected in Doctrine 3 : [issue tracking](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6272)

Until Doctrine 3 is released, I went with a solution that passed the test of time in production projects in my company. Everything is explained in this [blog post](https://medium.com/lebouchondigital/thread-safe-business-logic-with-doctrine-f09c633f6554)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [explicit transaction demarcation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#approach-2-explicitly), to hopefully prevent the deadlock in the first place. By default only `flush()` is wrapped in a transaction.

Alternatively, you might be able to change your procedure to use the DQL `UPDATE` query, which should be atomic.

Or re-submit the request back to the action (with some recursion limit).

I'm not sure there is going to be a good way of restarting the entity manager, but keeping the unit of work.